# HQL query to retrieve common tags from multiple Item object instances

Tags: java, sql, hql

Lets say I have query that gets following List Item Objects with Set of tags like this:

```
Item1{TagSet{tag1,tag2,tag3}}
Item2{TagSet{tag3,tag4,tag5}}
Item3{TagSet{tag6,tag7,tag8}}

Item1 Item2 Item3 are instances of Item object in List 
TagSet is Set Collection object
```

What HQL or SQL query would retrieve the `List of Items having tag3` and from that result `get list of all tags from thouse items that contain tag3` (`not including tag3`) eg. from the 3 items above?

Desired result would be:

```
TagSet{tag1, tag2, tag4, tag5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give us your schema, so I'm guessing here, but...

SQL:

```
select distinct *
from item
join tag on tag.item_id = item.id
where item.name = 'foo'
and tag.name != 'tag3'
and item.id in (select item_id from tag where name = 'tag3');
```

HQL:

```
entityManager
.createQuery("
    select t
    from Tag t
    where t.name != 'tag3'
    and t.item in (select t2.item from Tag t2 where t2.name = 'Tag3')
    and t.item.name = :name")
.setParateter("name", "foo")
.getResultList();
```

Then use tag.getItem() to get the Items for the tags returned.